# Getting "Failed to start system task System Task" - Airflow DAG/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, airflow

After I triggered and refreshed the dag task, it went from running, delayed, to failed. The error log from the airflow told me to check the error from sql server which I got "Failed to start system task System Task" when I checked the logs on my sql server docker container. I'm not sure if I need to specify a schema but the rest of the connection params are correct.

[entrypoint.sh]

```
"${AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_SRC_DB:=mssql+pyodbc://SA:P@SSW0RD@mssqlcsc380:1433/?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server}"
```

[dag.py]

```
with DAG (
    'mssql_380_dag',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        'owner' : 'me',
        'retries' : 1,
        'retry_delay' : dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
        }
    ) as dag:
    get_requests = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id = 'get_requests',
        mssql_conn_id = 'my_src_db',
        sql = 'select * from Request',
        dag = dag
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just that it couldn't notice the table so I specified the database which fixed the issue even though the database should of been recognized since I've passed it on the connection string.

```
sql = 'use csc380db; select * from Request',
```